# WEEKOFYEAR() not a valid partitioning function

Tags: mysql

I have need to partition a MySQL table by what week of the year it is. However, when I ran my partition query with **weekofyear()** as my partitioning expression I get this:

```
ERROR 1564 (HY000): This partition function is not allowed
```

I looked up the documentation and weekofyear() is a valid partitioning function since MySQL5.1.
Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Not to be snarky, but are you running 5.1?

Comment: That's the first thing I was afraid of too. But I checked and I'm running 5.5.21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weekofyear()` results depends on  default_week_format system variable, so it wasn't safe to use it as partitioning function. Since 5.5.9 `weekofyear()` has been removed from functions allowed for partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

`weekofyear` is forbidden but `yearweek` is not. `yearweek` return result as `202332` (or year * 100 + week) , so getting week from `yearweek` as easy as:

```sql
partition by hash(yearweek(current_timestamp()) % 100) partitions 52
```